# Is it legal to copy APIs and concepts of proprietary operating systems?

Tags: operating-system, software-distribution

Let's say I found publicly available documentation (not source code) for a proprietary operating system (for example, VxWorks). And let’s say I wrote my own operating system kernel, which would largely copy the API and concepts of this proprietary operating system.

(By "publicly available" I mean that I downloaded it from a torrent. And the developer of a proprietary operating system provides documentation only to clients)

Can the developer of this proprietary operating system make any claims against me if I publish my code on GitHub?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a legal question, and therefore off-topic on StackOverflow.  You could try https://law.stackexchange.com/ or (maybe) https://opensource.stackexchange.com/.  Asking programmers for legal advice is about as sensible as asking medical doctors for advice on car maintenance or cooking.  And the consequences of getting get bad advice could be a lot worse.

Comment: And the question is a bit naive.  A company can make a legal claim against you or threaten to do that on the flimsiest of evidence.  Whether they can make it stick ... in a court of law ... is a different thing.  But defending yourself against a legal claim is going to cost you money ... even if the claim is thrown out.  And there's little chance you will get that money back.

Comment: Finally, the Oracle vs Google lawsuit over the Java APIs shows that copyrights >can< apply to APIs.  But ask a practicing lawyer to explain that to you!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the existence of law.stackexchange.com and opensource.stackexchange.com. You're right, I should ask that question there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: Google LLC v. Oracle America, Inc.

From Wiki:

> The Court issued its decision on April 5, 2021. In a 6–2 majority, the Court ruled that Google's use of the Java APIs was within the bounds of fair use, reversing the Federal Circuit Appeals Court ruling and remanding the case for further hearing

Comment: If you need to know if that applies to what >you< intend to do ... ask a lawyer.